# ReactJS onClick slow response on mobile device

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile

I'm currently learning ReactJS.
I created a simple application and I got two buttons.
On a desktop everything works fine and smooth.
On my iPhone using Safari however, when I click the button there is a delay before the onClick action changes appear.

I read about the 300ms delay on mobile devices but none of the solutions given worked for me. Ref:  https://www.sitepoint.com/5-ways-prevent-300ms-click-delay-mobile-devices/

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './form_donation.scss';

function FormDonationAmount() {
    const [amount, setAmount] = useState(0);
    const [amountText, setAmountText] = useState(amount.toString());

    function updateAmount(amount: number) {
        if (amount > 99999) {
            setAmount(99999);
        } else if (amount < 0) {
            setAmount(0);
        } else {
            setAmount(amount);
        }
        setAmountText(amount.toString());
    }

    function handleAmountChange(e: any) {
        var parsed = parseInt(e.target.value);
        if (isNaN(parsed)) {
            setAmountText("");
            updateAmount(0);
            return;
        }
        updateAmount(parsed);
    }

    return (
        <div className="inputs">
            <div id="amount_input">
                <input type="number" onChange={handleAmountChange} value={amountText} />
                <button onClick={() => updateAmount(amount - 10)}>&#65293;</button>
                <button onClick={() => updateAmount(amount + 10)}>&#65291;</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default FormDonationAmount;
```

This is very frustrating for the user experience. Any ideas how I could fix this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it was my css that was absolutely massive for the mobile to handle. So yeah, big moving blurry things in the background are cool but not very optimised...